# PHP - function for mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

If I do this in PHP, it works fine and loops as expected:

```
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    writeme("UserID: " . $row["UserID"]);
}
```

But I keep wanting to abstract this out into a function I have called ExecuteQuery:

```
function ExecuteQuery($sql){
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result) {
    if($result != 1){
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // return recordset
    }
}else{
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "<br>";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql;
    echo $message;
    die();
}
```

}

This function works great in 2 out of 3 scenarios:

1- Works great for a query that returns 1 row, and I can access like this:

$rs = ExecuteQuery($sql);

$foo = $rs["UserID"];

2- Works great for a sql statement that returns no records, like an UPDATE or DELETE.

3- But when I try to get back a recordset that returns multiple records, and then loop through it, I get an infinite loop and my browser crashes. Like this:

```
$rs = ExecuteQuery($sql);
while ($row = $rs){
    writeme("UserID: " . $row["UserID"]);
}
```

How can I modify my while loop so it advances to each new record in the recordset and stops after the last record? I'm sure it's a dumb little thing, but I'm not expert with PHP yet. I'd really like my ExecuteQuery function to be able to handle all 3 scenarios, it's very handy.

Comment: Haven't seen a good solution yet...still hoping.

Comment: didnt the solution I provided work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_fetch_assoc() only returns one row of the result.  To get the next row, you need to call mysql_fetch_assoc() again.  One thing you could do is have your ExecuteQuery function return an array of arrays:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) !== false) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}
return $rows;
```

Also, you should not use the mysql_* functions as they are deprecated.  Try using PDO or mysqli_* instead.

Answer (score 1):

try `foreach($rs as $row){` instead of `while ($row = $rs){`

Comment: This will not fetch the next row.  It will simply iterate over the column values in a single row of results.

Comment: why wouldn't it fetch the next row, thats what foreach does, loops through the entire array. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I think you have the params backward. I get this: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `$rs` being the resultset. `foreach($rs as $row){ writeme("UserID: " . $row["UserID"]); }` doesn't work?

Comment: OK, looks like the original post was edited. It used to be foreach($row as $rs). The new (edit) way sort of works, but it iterates way too many times, and I think it's actually looping every character of every string or something odd.

Comment: use `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use while, use foreach:

```
$rs = ExecuteQuery($sql);
foreach ($rs as $row){
    writeme("UserID: " . $row["UserID"]);
}
```

Comment: I thought you were on to something, but now my looper goes about 20 times when there are only 2 records. I think it's looping every character in every string.