# (Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource) except the query returns data

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok.  So this code I'm running does not work at all.  When I ran the query directly on the server it worked, however this does not work on my webpage.  I've been through all the help pages and can't pinpoint the error.  Please help.

```
function getUserData($id) {
        $servername = "******************";
        $dbname = "***********";
        $sql_username = "************";
        $sql_password = "****************";
        $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $sql_username, $sql_password, $dbname);
        $userData = array();
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id ='".$id."'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

        $userData['id'] = $row['id'];   
        $userData['user_name'] = $row['username'];
        $userData['password'] = $row['password'];       
        $userData['aboutme'] = $row['aboutme'];     
        $userData['first_name'] = $row['fname'];
        $userData['last_name'] = $row['lname'];     
        $userData['gender'] = $row['gender'];
        $userData['user_email'] = $row['email'];    
        $userData['country'] = $row['country']; 
        $userData['language'] = $row['language'];   
        $userData['send_emails'] = $row['sendemails'];
        $userData['date'] = $row['date'];           
        }
        return $userData;
    }
    function getUserId($username) {
        $servername = "*********************";
        $dbname = "*********";
        $sql_username = "***********";
        $sql_password = "***********";
        $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $sql_username, $sql_password, $dbname);
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$username."'");
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            return $row2['user_id'];            
        }
    }
```

This is what calls the fucntions.

```
    $userData = getUserData(getUserId($_SESSION['valid_user']))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - function for mysql\_fetch\_assoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502568/php-function-for-mysql-fetch-assoc)

Comment: `mysql_connect($servername, $sql_username, $sql_password, $dbname)` `mysql_connect()` only accepts 3 basic parameters http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php. The 4th is not for what you think. This is [`mysqli_()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) syntax. You need to use `mysql_select_db()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: You're welcome. If you want, I can make it an answer to post it below, instead of just a comment, in order to close the question, where you can accept it and marked as solved. The choice is yours ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_connect($servername, $sql_username, $sql_password, $dbname)`

- [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) only accepts 3 basic parameters:

> bool mysql_select_db ( string $database_name [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

As per the manual:

**http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php**

- The 4th parameter is not for what you think. This is [`mysqli_()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) syntax.

You need to use `mysql_select_db()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

From the manual also:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

From [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php):

> resource mysql_connect ([ string $server = ini_get("mysql.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysql.default_user") [, string $password = ini_get("mysql.default_password") [, bool $new_link = false [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]] )

Opens or reuses a connection to a MySQL server.

---

- I also need to state that your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: As per usual, great answer sir Fred! All this `mysql_*` makes me a sad panda :-(

Comment: @Darren Thanks Darren. Yeah, one day... `mysql_` will be but a mere memory in someone's old 256k sticks of RAM.